# How to run container in a remote docker host with Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, deployment, server, cloud

I have two servers:

- Server A: Build server with Jenkins and Docker installed.
- Server B: Production server with Docker installed.

I want to build a Docker image in Server A, and then run the corresponding container in Server B. The question is then:

**What's the recommended way of running a container in Server B from Server A, once Jenkins is done with the docker build? Do I have to push the image to Docker hub to pull it in Server B, or can I somehow transfer the image directly?**

I'm really not looking for specific Jenkins plugins or stuff, but rather, from a security and architecture standpoint, what's the best approach to accomplish this?

I've read a ton of posts and SO answers about this and have come to realize that there are plenty of ways to do it, but I'm still unsure what's the ultimate, most common way to do this. I've seen these alternatives:

- Using `docker-machine`
- Using Docker Restful Remote API
- Using plain `ssh root@server.b "docker run ..."`
- Using Docker Swarm (I'm super noob so I'm still unsure if this is even an option for my use case)

Edit:

I run Servers A and B in Digital Ocean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Docker image can be saved to a regular tar archive:

```
docker image save -o <FILE> <IMAGE>
```

Docs here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_save/

Then `scp` this tar archive to another host, and run `docker load` to load the image:

```
docker image load -i <FILE>
```

Docs here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_load/

This `save-scp-load` method is rarely used. The common approach is to set up a private Docker registry behind your firewall. And push images to or pull from that private registry. This doc describes [how to deploy a container registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/). Or you can choose registry service provided by a third party, such as [Gitlab's container registry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/container_registry.html).

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. I wonder, what's the common approach used in the industry? To push the image to a registry and pull it in the docker host? or to transfer images from build to prod servers via scp?

Comment: The common approach is to set up a private Docker registry behind your firewall. And push images to or pull from that private registry.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot man. Can you please complement your answer with that last remark? I will mark it as accepted then.

Comment: Updated my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

When using Docker repositories, you only push/pull the layers which have been changed.
You can use [Docker REST API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.24/). Jenkins HTTP Request plugin can be used to make HTTP requests. You can run Docker commands directly on a remote Docker host setting the DOCKER_HOST environment variable. To export an the environment variable to the current shell:

```
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://your-remote-server.org:2375"
```

Please be aware of the security concerns when allowing TCP traffic. [More info](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/).
Another method is to use SSH Agent Plugin in Jenkins.